# Function in wordpress 'Calculated Form Fields' plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm making an estimate form with the [calculated form plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/calculated-fields-form/), and I'm trying to add a function to get the date, if it's a Sunday I wanna add $10 to the summary

[image: 1]

Comment: You should add a minimum examble of code, to better understand what you need and how to help you.

Comment: As the question is part of a custom plugin, I guess you are better off creating a ticket in the [support](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/calculated-fields-form/) section of said plugin